# Where did the tool bar go in object mode? Blender 2.8

Tags: object-mode

I am adding a torus and in previous versions of Blender, when you added the torus, there was a tool bar on the left hand side where you could add or subtract segments.

I have moved to Blender 2.8 and I can no longer find this tool bar.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this is what you are looking for[image]

Every time you create an object you will see it.

Good Luck.

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you so much for your help. Hopefully this will help some other newbie too.

Thank you very much

Comment: I just started with Blender and my menu looks different, so I don't have the same options. https://ibb.co/q0WhKnZ Can you help me?

Comment: That menu only apears when you create a new object, before you move it or anything. Also, you could check videos like this that i made https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMbc2e_SN_Y , and i'll be happy to help you 
 if you have more questions. Good luck